# display image from object with select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How i can display image from object with javascript instead of putting link of image on value, here is demo [Demo Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLLrBX?editors=1010)

I did this but what i want is to put it in object and every selection have a price, when user select from left to right  to sum in the end in a div.

```
function displayImage(elem) {
    var image = document.getElementById("canvas");
    image.src = elem.value;
}

function displayImages(elem) {
    var image = document.getElementById("canvass");
    image.src = elem.value;
}

function same() {
    if (document.getElementById("canvas").src ==
        document.getElementById("canvass").src) {
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "13$";
    }
}
var silver = {
    image: 'https://lol-eloboosting.com/assets/images/divisions/1_3.png',
    price: 20
};
var gold = {
    image: 'https://lol-eloboosting.com/assets/images/divisions/2_1.png',
    price: 25
};
var platina = {
    image: 'https://lol-eloboosting.com/assets/images/divisions/3_1.png',
    price: 35
};
var platina = {
    image: 'https://lol-eloboosting.com/assets/images/divisions/4_1.png',
    price: 45
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you could do that as below, you have saved `image url and text` to display in `object`, now you could use `if condition` along event listener `change`, as below, I have not used your codes it for `reference example` that you could try something similar.

```js
var one = {
 url : "https://via.placeholder.com/200/111/fff",
  txt : "Hey my value is one!!!"
};

var two = {
 url : "https://via.placeholder.com/200/ff1/fff",
  txt : "Hey my value is two!!!"
};

var three = {
 url : "https://via.placeholder.com/200/3f2/fff",
  txt : "Hey my value is three!!!"
};

var slt = document.querySelector("select");
var ig = document.querySelector("img");
var para = document.createElement("p");

slt.addEventListener("change",function(){
 if(this.value == 1){
   ig.src = one.url;
    para.textContent = one.txt;
    document.body.append(para);
  }
  if(this.value == 2){
   ig.src = two.url;
    para.textContent = two.txt;
    document.body.append(para);
  }
  if(this.value == 3){
   ig.src = three.url;
    para.textContent = three.txt;
    document.body.append(para);
  }
});
```

```html
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/111/fff">
```

Comment: wow, thanks for this solution! but how i can sum between 2 select option? if user select silver with price 10 and second select is gold with price 25 to display total on div?

Comment: Welcome @CIonut :-), you mean sum of values from both select, if so you need to create another function to get value of both select and that prints out or append output in new variable or a new tag. Break your problem into function could help here.

Comment: Can you look at my code please, sorry if i disturb you with my silly question but i am trying to learn javascript. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvvMEN

Comment: It's okay @CIonut Check this jsFiddle might help you, went so lengthy https://jsfiddle.net/g2r6h408/1/, I'm using single object for both select, you can define one more and try.

Comment: Thank you Sir, have a nice day!